# Commision on stock market

Tags: nouns, ambiguity, finance

Is it correct to use word commision as a synonym to order on stock market? In meaning: an instruction from customers to brokers to buy or sell on the exchange.
I know that commision is a fee or percentage for broker for services rendered. But I found out that is commision synonym for order, or placing. So is it correct in this meaning?

I'm asking about noun commision with one 's'.

Comment: There is no such word as [commision](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commision). It has to be [commission](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commission):
"6 : a fee paid to an agent or employee for transacting a piece of business or performing a service; especially : a percentage of the money received from a total paid to the agent responsible for the business"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Commission* can be used to mean "place an order for", but it's usually used in respect of works of art or other particularly large concrete items ("commission a portrait", "commission a concerto", "commission an aircraft carrier"). It appears to be related to having made a commitment to pay for the work.

As you say, *commission* has a particular meaning for brokers, where they are paid a fee for services rendered.

It would be inadvisable to use the word in a different way when dealing with brokers. At best it would require effort to be certain of the meaning; at worst it could be distinctly ambiguous.

Comment: +1, just because you can do something doesn't necessarily mean you should, and here I agree that it's inadvisable. All the more so because it's reasonable to consider "if I had to ask to be sure the meaning was okay, then maybe others would be unsure too".

Comment: It's not about what one should do or not. It's been already used widely in the code in this meaning. I have to think now or does it make any sense to put extra effort to replace it.

Answer (score 5):

*Commission* can be used as a verb to mean ‘To give authority to act; to empower, authorize; to entrust with an office or duty’, or, again, ‘To give a commission or order for; to order’. It is probably in one or other of these ways that it is being used where you have seen it.

Comment: thanks. But I meant commision as a noun with one 's'. Is it still correct?

Comment: No, it's always spelt as _commission_.

Comment: Commission can be either (a) The act of granting the authority to carry out a particular task or (b) The authority so granted. So you might say "The broker has my commission to purchase stock." The single 's' is a variant (non-preferred) spelling.

Comment: @Fortiter. Do you have a source for the use of a single 's'?

Comment: I've found some, but maybe it's only typos? http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_does_commision_work (titel)

Comment: Do a verbatim search on Google for "commision". The results are enlightening or depressing depending upon your stance.

Comment: I did but still I could not decide or is it correct in this particular meaning.

Comment: @Fortiter. The COCA <http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) has 12 records for _commision_ and 32435 for _commission_. The figures from the BNC http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/ are 7 and 10191. The OED gives only _commission_.

Comment: @Borys: You do seem to take some convincing! The single-s version is definitely a spelling mistake, and the one and only word *commission* has multiple meanings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Are you sure of that? Because I'm getting really confused here...

Comment: @Borys: Of course I'm sure! So is everyone else who's mentioned the matter here. All that's happening is that you would *like* to think there are two different words because you understand two different senses. There are a few cases where things like that can happen (*practice/practise*, for example), but this isn't one of them. Fortiter's comment about *commision* being a "non-preferred variant spelling" is misleading. It's ***never*** considered valid by ***any*** "authorities".

Comment: Even Google gives 60 times as many returns for ‘commission’ as for ‘commision’.

Comment: FWIW, [spellcheck.com](http://www.spellcheck.net/commission) gives this percentage breakdown for the different ways people misspell the word: commision:56% comission:26% commisson:2% comision:2%.